# How to change text size of CCC Line Chart in Pentaho CDE

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-cde

I have successfully added a CCC line chart to my dashboard but am unable to change the text size associated with axis / value labels. Has anyone had any luck with this?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which axis font size you want to increase.
But in component panel click on advance properties of specific component(ccc chart)which you have selected,search for font and change the font size based on axis where you want to change.